# ASP.NET MVC Edit controller using scaffolding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I am new to Entity Framework and using scaffolding. This may get confusing. I am trying to display a record from another table that is link to the table for the controller.

For instance, I have a DeviceLogController that is associated with a DeviceLog table. Within the DeviceLog table I have a field that is a foreign key to another table - Device (DeviceId). I am able to view DeviceId and field found in the Device table. However I would like to view table that is now link to the Device table. Device has a foreign key in it that is linked to a DeviceLocation table. Which has a DeviceID and LocationID foreign keys. I want to get the LocationID because DeviceLocation is linked to Location Table - my ultimate goal. I have tried various combinations however have not succeeded. Really confusing.

This is my code from my Controller.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)

    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        DeviceLog devicelog = db.DeviceLogs.Find(id);
        DeviceStatu deviceStatu = db.DeviceStatus.Find(id);

        if (devicelog == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "DeviceID", devicelog.DeviceID);
        ViewBag.DeviceLogTypeID = new SelectList(db.DeviceLogTypes, "DeviceLogTypeID", "DeviceLogTypeDescription", devicelog.DeviceLogTypeID);

        //Device information to view
        ViewBag.DeviceID = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "InventoryNumber", devicelog.DeviceID);
        ViewBag.InventoryNumber = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "InventoryNumber", devicelog.DeviceID);
        ViewBag.SerialNumber = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "SerialNumber", devicelog.DeviceID);
        ViewBag.DateRcvdNumber = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "DateReceived", devicelog.DeviceID);
        ViewBag.PriceNumber = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "Price", devicelog.DeviceID);

        //location information to view
        ViewBag.DeviceLocationID = new SelectList(db.DeviceStatus, "DeviceID", "DeviceLocationID", devicelog.DeviceLocation.LocationID);
        return View(devicelog);
    }
```

or

```
//location information to view
        ViewBag.DeviceLocationID = new SelectList(db.DeviceLocations, "DeviceID", "DeviceLocationID", devicelog.Device.DeviceID);
        return View(devicelog);
```

This is from my DeviceLog Edit view

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Device.DeviceLocations, "DeviceLocationID")
```

Comment: Are you using entity framework or ado.net for your application

Comment: I am using entity framework